# Trying to identify an ancient ActiveX control

Tags: vba, ms-access, activex

I'm trying to update an ancient Access '97 database that makes extensive use of VBA to a newer version of Access.

On trying to upgrade the database file the system refers to (but cannot find) an ActiveX control called `ActiveXCtl35` used in the VBA which looks like it's used as a file picker:

```
ActiveXCtl35.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
ActiveXCtl35.FilterIndex = 1
ActiveXCtl35.InitDir = "d:\import\"
ActiveXCtl35.ShowOpen
```

I can find precisely *one* reference to this on Google, and it doesn't have any useful information.

Can anyone please help identify what this is, and how we can replace it with something supported?

Comment: there's _two_ references now... :p

Comment: you can use `application.FileDialog` to replace filepicker code

Comment: Can you provide more context? Was this ActiveX control placed on a form? If so, you can usually track this down using its properties.

Comment: @ErikA the control is referred to by name in VBA e.g. `ActiveXctl35.filename = ...`

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Is that code on a form? If so, can you share the form? (`SaveAsText acForm, FormName, FileName`). The object has to be declared and instantiated somewhere, and that can be either in code, as a form control, as a report control. It doesn't appear out of the void.

Comment: @ErikA OK - got you.  It is instantiated on the form, with the class set to `MSComDlg.CommonDialog.1`

Comment: Well, seems like you've answered your own question there ;). Afaik these Common Dialog controls are still present, just not 64-bit compatible.